# Two controllers inside of a UIPopoverController: having issues with frames

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, ios5, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController with two view controllers inside of it. I'm building it like so:

```
CommentsPopoverController *commentsPopoverController = [[CommentsPopoverController alloc] init];
self.delegate = commentsPopoverController;
commentsPopoverController.navigationItem.title = @"Comments";
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]                               initWithRootViewController:commentsPopoverController];
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
```

Inside my commentsPopoverController I have this:

```
commentsViewController = [[CommentsViewController alloc] init];
commentsViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

addCommentsViewController = [[AddCommentViewController alloc] init];
addCommentsViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, commentsViewController.view.bounds.size.height - 200, 320, 346);
addCommentsViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

[self.view addSubview:addCommentsViewController.view];
[self.view addSubview:commentsViewController.view];
```

So when I first load the popover, the addCommentsViewController is hidden by the commentsViewController. When I reveal it, it looks like this:

[image: popover with both controllers visible]

So far so good. The problem I'm having is that from here, when the user rotates the device or shows the keyboard or shows the keyboard THEN rotates the device things start to get out of whack. The top view controller (commentsViewController) which is a UITableView always does the right thing no matter what the orientation is or whether or not the keyboard is showing. But the bottom view controller (addCommentsViewController) doesn't automatically change it's origin.y to stay directly under the top view controller.

So I've basically had to hack the crap out of my code to keep the addCommentsViewController directly under the commentsViewController by constantly calculating the height of the top view controller so that I could adjust the bottom view controller's origin.y. This involved dropping in NSNotifications for the keyboard's show/hide state and for the device's orientation and constantly recalculating. Very hackish and ugly.

So my question (finally) is: Is there an easier way of controlling these views or am I stuck hacking it the way I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle rotation, there are two appropriate techniques.  One is that you make `CommentsPopoverController`'s view a subclass of `UIView` that overrides `layoutSubviews` to lay out your two views properly.  The other is that you define `viewDidLayoutSubviews` on `CommentsPopoverController` to lay out your views.  If you lay out your views in either of these methods, you shouldn't have to subscribe to rotation notifications.

As for moving your view out from under the keyboard, that is discussed in the [*Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7).  Part of the technique involves subscribing to keyboard will show/did hide notifications.

I assume your `CommentsViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`, because `UITableViewController` takes care of adjusting the table view when the keyboard is hidden or shown.

Comment: I'm going to look into viewDidLayoutSubviews now and see what that's all about it. As for keyboard show/hide, I am currently already subscribing to the NSNotifications. If I can get the viewDidLayoutSubviews or layoutSubviews technique to work I will come back and accept your answer.  Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: I ended up adding viewDidLayoutSubviews to the view that was misbehaving and made the update within that and it seems to have done the trick, great answer thank you.